# hHow to manipulate data in react

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, antd

I am trying to add custom filter to my antd table, but I am having an issue with using the data.

```
get valuations() {
    var arr = this.props.valuation;
    var valArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      valArray.push({
        date: arr[i].registered_date,
        name: arr[i].full_name,
        year: arr[i].year
      });
    }
    return valArray;
  }

render(){
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Date",
      dataIndex: "date",
      },
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
    },
    {
      title: "Year",
      dataIndex: "year"
    },
  ];

  return(
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={this.valuations}
    />
  )
}
```

So I get the data on the table, but I want to add a custom filter. So I need to play with valArray. My problem is how do I use the array returned from the function valuations. I know how to filter an array, but I just don't know how to use the array outside of its function.

I tried setting a new state with the data but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "i just don't know how to use the array outside of its function" ? You need to provide an example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: i tried calling the function outside of the render and assign the returned value to a variable and use that variable as the dataSource for the table. It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate `this.valuations`. Create input box or another element to get a filter value:-

lets here am filtering your name attribute:

Now

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.valuations();
}

valuations = () => {
    // set state instead of return here you can optimize your code using filter method here
    this.setState({data: valArray})
}

nameFilterHandler = (inputValue) => {
    const {valuation} = this.props;

    //Edited Here.
    valuation.filter((data) => {
        data.name = data.full_name,
        data.date = data.registered_date,
        return date.full_name && data.full_name.match(this.state.inputValue)
    })

    this.setState({data: valuation});
}

return(
    <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={this.state.data}
    />
)
```

try this and think about all filters and create a generic method for all.